# How to get the job artifacts of a child pipeline with GitLab API?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

```
job 1 ________ child-pipeline ________ job 3 (x)
         /                       \
job 2 __/                         \___ job 4
```

I'm trying to reach the artifact of `job 3`. Here is where I reached so far:

I need the ID of the `job 3` according to [the GitLab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html#get-job-artifacts). I use [Gitbeaker](https://github.com/jdalrymple/gitbeaker) to simplify things in NodeJS but if you are not familiar with it it's fine to answer with curl examples.

First, I got the pipelines of the commit then I retrieved the jobs of those pipelines but those gave me only `job 1` and `job 2` even though the docs says "In GitLab 13.3 and later, this endpoint returns data for any pipeline including child pipelines. ([ref](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#list-pipeline-jobs))"

```js
api.Pipelines.all(PROJECT_ID, {
  sha: 'commit_sha',
  ref: 'master',
}).then(async (commitPipelines) => {
  for await (const pipeline of commitPipelines) {
    api.Jobs.showPipelineJobs(PROJECT_ID, pipeline.id, {
      scope: 'success',
    }).then((pipelineJobs) => {
      console.log(pipelineJobs);
    });
  }
});
```

Then I picked another route to get the commit status of on the `child-pipelines` stage assuming I would get the pipeline IDs of the child pipelines and I would reach the jobs of them. But the IDs that I got were not the pipeline IDs.

```js
api.Commits.status(PROJECT_ID, 'commit_sha', {
  stage: 'child-pipelines',
  ref: 'master',
}).then((state) => {
  state.forEach(async (commitStatus) => {
    if (commitStatus.status === 'success') {
      console.log(commitStatus);
    }
  });
});
```

In the end, both of my approaches got stuck at the child pipelines. Maybe, I overlook at this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out that Gitlab has an endpoint to access the child pipelines which is called [pipeline bridges](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#list-pipeline-bridges) which helped me to find a solution.

```js
async function getCommitPipelines(commitId) {
  return await api.Pipelines.all(GITLAB_PROJECT_ID, {
    sha: commitId,
    ref: 'master',
    status: 'success',
  });
}

async function getPipelineJobs(pipelineId) {
  return await api.Jobs.showPipelineJobs(GITLAB_PROJECT_ID, pipelineId, {
    scope: 'success',
  });
}

async function getPipelineBridges(pipelineId) {
  return await api.Jobs.showPipelineBridges(GITLAB_PROJECT_ID, pipelineId);
}

async function downloadArtifactFile(jobId) {
  return await api.Jobs.downloadSingleArtifactFile(
    GITLAB_PROJECT_ID,
    jobId,
    'artifact-file.json',
  );
}

async function downloadCommitArtifacts(commitId) {
  const commitArtifacts = [];
  // 1. Get all of the pipelines of a the commit
  const commitPipelines = await getCommitPipelines(commitId);

  for (const commitPipeline of commitPipelines) {
    // 2. Get all of the downstream pipelines of each pipeline
    const bridgePipelines = await getPipelineBridges(commitPipeline.id);

    for (const bridgePipeline of bridgePipelines) {
      // 3. Get all the child pipeline jobs
      // Here you are looking at the job 3 and job 4
      const job = await getPipelineJobs(
        bridgePipeline.downstream_pipeline.id
      );

      for (const job of jobs) {
        if (job.name !== 'job-3') {
          continue;
        }

        // 4. Get the artifact (the artifact file in this case) from the job
        const artifactFile = await downloadArtifactFile(job.id);
        commitArtifacts.push(artifactFile);
      }
    }
  }

  return commitArtifacts;
}
```